# Middle clicking help takes me to #

Tags: feature-request, bug, help-center

On any page on the site if I middle click the help icon it takes me to the same page but with `#` appended onto the end of the link. For example, doing so from:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Takes me to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/#
```

I would assume it should take me to the help centre or:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help
```

---

Tagging as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) because I'm not sure which one it is. If this is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design) I would like the behaviour to change to link to the help centre.

---

Note: I am mainly active over on SFF and I first noticed this behaviour there. A quick cursory check on some other sites (PPCG, Workplace, Software Engineering, Super User) reveals this happens on them too so I'd assume it's network wide.

Comment: Interesting.  Ctrl +Click opens the dropdown without navigating.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Aye does the same on the other menu items too.

Comment: It should be noted the "Review" icon works as expected. Middle-click that and you get the "Review" page in a new tab. In fact, the "Help" icon is the _only one_ that displays this behavior- The rest have a page they redirect to.

Comment: @Kendra Inbox, reputation, review and the hamburger all work as expected. User profile and "site name" also link to where you'd expect them too. Only help seems to borken.

Comment: I was literally editing that in as you said that. :)

Comment: So... if this is a `feature-request`, I'd downvote it. If it's a `bug` I wouldn't vote at all... *What do I do?* :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You'd upvote it cos That's What Monkey's Do.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I prefer "software simian" thank you very much.

Comment: Arguably, the Tooltip says "*Help Center **and other resources***" (emphasis mine). So it makes sense we are not redirected to any of these *resources* for as long as they are not merged in the same single-page.

Comment: No Kaiido: it doesn't make sense to open the same page as you currently are. People trying to open the "Help Center etc." expect at least the Help Center to open.

Comment: @Cœur it doesn't "open" any page, it just scroll to the first element named `""` (i.e to the top). Yes, using an anchor that doesn't really link to somewhere is not perfect, but it is so commonly done that we can't even call it bad anymore. And once again, I didn't say it makes sense to use an anchor, but it does make sense we are not redirected to /help/ which doesn't provide any link to any sub-items of the dropdown. So if FR there should be, I think it should be to create a centralised /help-and-others/

Comment: Now for a quick workaround, this link could be simply disabled by removing the `href` altogether since it is not even needed (CSS does handle the `cursor` pointer)

Answer (score 13):

The expected behavior when clicking on such icons is to open a menu that belongs to the clicked icon. That icon is a svg image wrapped within an anchor element (example is from the help icon):

```
<a href="#" class="-link js-help-button topbar-icon-on" title="Help Center and other resources">
```

By default, clicking on an anchor element will navigate the browser to the URL denoted in the `href` attribute. Here it is `#`. However, with JavaScript, you can add an event listener which is handled before doing this step. This is done here. When clicking on those buttons, a function is called to display an appropriate `<div>` element (the menu that you see) on the page. The function also prevents the event being bubbled up, which means that the browser does not navigate you to the URL denoted in the `href` attribute.

However, by default, middle clicks are not treated as a simple mouse click event. That leads to the function that stops the bubbling and display the menu thing not being called. So the browser gets a navigation call to the URL denoted in the `href` attribute. This is by design. By this, you get navigated to `#`. The browser makes it as `currentURL#` which is what you see.

If you want to prevent this, you have to listen to "middleclicks" too.

PS: A small info for those that is curious about the "middle click". If your mouse has two buttons and a scrolling wheel, you can do a middle click by pressing the scrolling wheel (if the mouse supports it). Some people may have a mouse with three buttons. Clicking on the middle button performs a ... heh ... "middle click".

Comment: So, what about replacing `href="#"` to `href="/help"`?

Comment: @Cœur:  Because clicking the Help button doesn't *simply* redirect you to the Help page.  You get *quite a lot* of other options.

Comment: The same happens with right click + "open in new tab" on Chromium. So I would suggest to just put a useful URL as the link, instead of trying to catch all kinds of interaction.

Comment: It's entirely possible with how SO does things to make the icon take you to "help" on a middle click- The review icon does exactly this. It opens a menu on click, opens the "Review" page in a new tab on middle click. Same with the other "menu display" items.

Comment: What is the conclusion?

Comment: @Kendra the main difference between this item and the other ones is that all the other ones points to a document where all sub-items that should have appeared in the dropdown are accessible. /help/ doesn't point to the sub-items contained in its dropdown.

Comment: If you rely on JS to have an element open a menu on click, don't use an anchor but a span tag. If you use an anchor, give it a sensible target url. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Bergi true that (I also recommend that in my projects). But say that to a lot developers. I see that pretty frequently. It only does not get discovered often because doing a middle mouse click or running a web browser without an active JavaScript engine is rare. It is a habit of mine to check the linking information at the bottom of the browser when my mouse changes to a pointer icon.